# onResume() getting called on pressing back arrow. Please see details

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onresume

I have a method in `onResume()` which fetches user's data and should get called when user launch the app. This is working fine.

The problem is that for example after opening 'Settings' when I tap/click on the back arrow, the method in `onResume()` gets called again and user data starts getting fetched again.

What I want is, I want that method to get called only when user launches the app and not every time the user transition back from settings to main activity.

Here's the `onResume()` in `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        fetchUserData();

    }
```

Here's how I transition to `Settings.java`:

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

Please let me how can I restrict the `fetchUserData()` to get called only when user launches the app and not again when user transition back to main activity from any other activity by tapping/clicking on back arrow.

Sorry, if question seems to be badly formatted. I'm still a beginner here.

Comment: onResume is always called when ever you land on that activity weather it is for first time or coming back from another Activity

Comment: first read the activity lifecycle -> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html  After read this you automatically understand your question is wrong

Comment: @RakshitNawani isn't there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: try put fetchUserData(); in onCreate(). it will call one time only.

Comment: Well set   fetchUserData(); inside your onCreate

Comment: @HammadNasir You can move your code from onResume() to onCreate() method. OnCreate() method gets called only once until whole Activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

if you want the method to be called only once when the activity opens move it inside `OnCreate()` method.`OnResume()` can be called several times.You can see the documentation of acttivity lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt the following code, by setting a flag/indicator so that only wanted returns are processed (eg set resume_state to RESUMESTATE_NOTHING except when starting an intent after which you want to fetchUserData:-

```
public class AisleListByCursorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static int RESUMESTATE_NOTHING = 0;
public final static int RESUMESTATE_AISLEADD = 1;
public final static int RESUMESTATE_AISLESTOCK = 2;
public final static int RESUMESTATE_AISLEDELETE =3;
public final static int RESUMESTATE_AISLEUPDATE = 4;
public int resume_state = RESUMESTATE_NOTHING;
public ShopsCursorAdapter currentsca;
public AislesCursorAdapter currentaca;
public ShopListSpinnerAdapter currentslspa;
public long currentshopid;

private final static String THIS_ACTIVITY = "AisleListByCursorActivity";
private final ShopperDBHelper shopperdb = new ShopperDBHelper(this,null, null, 1);

private ListView aisleslistview;
private Cursor csr;
private int shopid = 0;

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    switch (resume_state) {
        case RESUMESTATE_AISLEADD:case RESUMESTATE_AISLEUPDATE: {
            Cursor csr = shopperdb.getAislesPerShopAsCursor(currentshopid);
            currentaca.swapCursor(csr);
            resume_state = RESUMESTATE_NOTHING;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            resume_state = RESUMESTATE_NOTHING;
        }
    }
}
```

........

```
public void aalbcadd(View view) {
    resume_state = RESUMESTATE_AISLEADD;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AisleAddActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Caller",THIS_ACTIVITY);
    intent.putExtra("SHOPID", currentshopid);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method in `OnStart()` or `onCreate()` rather than `onResume()`. for reference - please see this link for better understanding of Android LifeCycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to be called only once you must put that method in `onCreate` method of Activity. Because `onResume` is always called you come back to the activity as per Android lifecycle.  So just replace you method `fetchUserData();` into `onCreate` like below:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_list); 
            fetchUserData();
    }

     @Override
      protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      }
```